# Custom Entity object property doesn't update in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: wcf, silverlight, binding, c1richtextbox

I have a Silverlight Application with Domain Service.

Entity Object (Part Of) :

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="MiaoulisModel", Name="AbroadTravel")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class AbroadTravel : EntityObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _Description;
        }
        set
        {
            OnDescriptionChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Description");
            _Description = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Description");
            OnDescriptionChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _Description;
    partial void OnDescriptionChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnDescriptionChanged();
```

Here is my Partial Classe with Custom Property :

```
public partial class AbroadTravel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [DataMember]
        public String ShortDescription
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Description == null)
                {
                    return this.Description;
                }
                if (this.Description.Contains("\n"))
                {
                    var index = this.Description.IndexOf("\n");
                    if (index < 50)
                    {
                        return this.Description.Substring(0, index) + " [...]";
                    }
                }
                if (this.Description.Length >= 50)
                {
                    return this.Description.Substring(0, 50) + " [...]";
                }

                return this.Description;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my DataGrid, I have :

```
<c1:Column x:Name="dgcDescription" Binding="{Binding Path=ShortDescription}" Width="4*" />
```

And a RichTextBox with :

```
<c1:C1RichTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

When I update the RichTextBox which the Description value, the DataGrid with the ShortDescription does not update.

Any Idea ? (I do not use MVVM, I use the Code Behind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the UI that the property `ShortDescription` (an autocalculated property) has changed, when you change the property `Description`.

In order to do that, you need to raise the `PropertyChanged`-Event for the property `ShortDescription` when the property `Description` changed. Otherwise has the UI now chance to know that the property `ShortDescription` has changed and that it should update the binding.

In CodeBehind (**in Silverlight-Client-Project**)  you can do it like so:

```
public partial class AbroadTravel
  // omitted your code

  partial void OnDescriptionChanged(){
     RaisePropertyChanged("ShortDescription");
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved my Problem ;). Actually, my Partial Class was on the Server Side, I moved it to Client Side and add the OnDescriptionChanged and now it works :) Many thanks